# My bubble sort code with vector in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have tried to write a bubble sort program in c++.
The user should type in a few numbers randomly and then the algorithm should sort the numbers from minimum to maximum. However, evertime I type in some numbers, the highest value seems to be zero (0). I have tried to debug my code but i cannot find the problem.
Here is my code:

**EDIT: Thanks for the reply guys =)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    int tal;

    cout <<"Write some number"<<endl;

    while(cin>>tal){
        v.push_back(tal);
    }

    for(int a=0; a<v.size(); a++){
        cout<<v[a]<<endl; //Checking for my inputs
    }

    bool change=true;
    //    vector<int> v = {1,2,5,6,3,4,10};
    while(change){
    change=false;
        for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
            if (v[i]>v[i+1]){
               swap(v[i], v[i+1]);
               change=true;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "----------" << endl;
    for (int j=0; j<v.size(); j++){
        cout << v[j] << endl;  //Checking my sorting results
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are testing items outside the vector, with `v[i+1]`

Comment: For these kind of problems it's quite useful to use `std::vector::at` instead of `operator[]`, i.e. `v.at(i)` instead of `v[i]`. The `at` member function will throw an out of bounds exception whenever performing out of bounds access. Once you are sure your code is OK, then you can switch back to `operator[]` (for speed reasons).

Answer (score 3):

`v[i]>v[i+1]`, here `i+1` may be `v.size()`, then you are accessing out of vector's boundary